# Story about a colony on a forest planet

Tags: story-identification, aliens, hard-sci-fi

A number of years ago, I read a novel of a colony on a world that was covered by dense forest. The native people were human-like but had prehensile toes and lived in the forest canopy layer in villages that were a single tree that recognised them and would allow entry.  The natives bond with a semi-sentient "pet" that in a twist at the end turns out to actually be stage of a plant's lifecycle.  The humans are destroying forest for commercial gain and one of their ships crashs and is discovered by the natives who have a special bond with their "Home Tree" (no its not Avatar).

One other detail I remember is the fact that the planet's surface is extremely "hostile" and dangerous.

I am trying to find it again but can't remember the book or the author (I seem to recall he/she wrote some Star Trek stories as well)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The author is Alan Dean Foster, there are two novels involving the humans on the forested world. The one your thinking of is [Mid-Flinx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-Flinx) the protagonist is Flinx.

[image: Mid-Flinx]

The first novel introducing the string of Humanx Commonwealth stories in 1975 is [Midworld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midworld). The protagonist is  a native named Born.

[image: did the original size offend someone's sensibilities?]

And as  Dijkgraaf points out the author wrote some of those Star Trek Logs:

[image: Showing Alan Dean Foster wrote the Star Trek Logs]

Look! prehensile toes! And they live in a Home-tree:
[image: showing prehensile toes]

At least Ruumahum looks more like a six legged hippo than an 'angry [thanator](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Thanator)'.)

Comment: And yes, Alan Dean Foster also wrote Star Trek books.

Comment: Midworld is the one! The cover is exactly what I remembered. Thanks